# Constraints on low dimensional representations of data

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, loss-functions, autoencoders, constraint

Is there literature discussing introduction of constraints to loss functions in order to specify certain structures on low dimensional representations? If so, how do they compare the efficacy of the constrained representation?

Specifically, suppose I have a data set for which I have found a low dimensional representation (via tSNE or UMap), which has been clustered via K-means. I want to determine whether this is a reasonable representation for another data set that I have. My current idea is to create an autoencoder, that maps the data to the same dimension, then attempts to reconstruct the original data. By including a term in the loss function that penalizes points in the low dimensional representation, for being far away from the nearest centroid in the K-means cluster, I can emphasize the desired structure in the low dimension, and study the reconstruction error in order to judge the efficacy of the representation.

However, this is computationally intensive, and seems like too much of a brute force method. Are there any papers, or simple ideas that would help with this?

Comment: I understand the procedure you described, but not sure I understand your goal (which makes it hard to evaluate the procedure). Can you say more about what you're trying to do and why? On a side,note, clustering t-SNE outputs isn't a great idea because t-SNE can tend create artifactual clusters (there are some posts on this site showing examples of this). Not sure about UMAP in that regard.

Comment: Currently, we're interested in studying consistency of cell development between animals. Given a cell lineage in a low dimensional space (which we can think of as related to latent variables, which take the form of a directed graph), obtained from a single data set, can we determine whether cell lineage from another animal matches the previously constructed cell lineage. If not, can we construct a  cell lineage as similar as possible to that of the original mouse (perhaps by adding or removing certain nodes in certain locations). How can we quantify how close the obtained lineages are.

Comment: Basically, I am currently thinking that I may be able to use reconstruction error to determine the quality of low dimensional representations, with hopes to compare possible representations.